# JSON with SwiftUI using Array

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am new to SwiftUI and only used UIKit before. I tried to use JSON to show a title but all tutorial videos work with lists. I dont want to use any list with JSON which shows all data. Only want to fetch for example the second or a specific array for title.

How can I remove the list in SwiftUI?
My View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
            List(networkManager.posts) { post in
            HStack {
            Text(String(post.points))
            Text(post.title)
                    }}
            .navigationBarTitle("H4X0R NEWS")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

NetworkManager:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=front_page") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.posts = results.hits
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

And my struct files for Json:

```
struct Results: Decodable {
    let hits: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return objectID
    }
    let objectID: String
    let points: Int
    let title: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want to use any list with JSON which shows all data. Only want
> to fetch for example the second or a specific array for title.

You can use a computed property to access the specific element (and its title) from the `posts` array:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    // return the title of the second item in the `posts` array
    var title: String {
        guard networkManager.posts.count >= 2 else { 
            // decide what to do when data is not yet loaded or count is <= 1
            return "Loading..."
        }
        return networkManager.posts[1].title
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text(title)
                .navigationBarTitle("H4X0R NEWS")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```